# C# Linq String[] list minus from String[] list

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say

```
string[] admins = "aron, mike, bob";
string[] users = "mike, katie, sarah";
```

How can I take the users and strip out anyone from the admins.

the result should be "katie, sarah"; (mike was removed)

Is there a nice Linq way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
// as you may know, this is the right method to declare arrays       
string[] admins = {"aron", "mike", "bob"};
string[] users = {"mike", "katie", "sarah"};

// use "Except"
var exceptAdmins = users.Except( admins );
```

Comment: Actually, that's not right either: `string[] admins = {"aron", "mike", "bob"}; `

Comment: This:
string[] customers = Roles.GetUsersInRole("customer");
     string[] admins = Roles.GetUsersInRole("admin");


     string[] result = customers.Except(customers, admins);

 gives me this error:

The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Except<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

```
users.Except(admins);
```

See more set operations:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx

Answer (score 5):

The easiest would to be use [`IEnumerable<T>.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx):

```
var nonAdmins = users.Except(admins);
```